# Getting marker from map.data class use geojson google maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

first of all I was initiate marker from geojson, and how I can get the marker if i want use marker for listener/action?

this is my script

```
var map;

function initMap() {
    //makes map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -6.9034482, lng: 107.6081381},
        zoom: 9,
        styles: [{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"saturation":43},{"lightness":-11},{"hue":"#0088ff"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"hue":"#ff0000"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":99}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#808080"},{"lightness":54}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ece2d9"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ccdca1"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#767676"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"poi","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.natural","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#b8cb93"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi.sports_complex","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi.medical","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi.business","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]}]
        });

    //load marker from geojson
    map.data.loadGeoJson('<?php echo base_url().'index.php/json_site/geojsongetmap'?>');

    // set style marker
    map.data.setStyle(function(feature){
        var tit = feature.getProperty('nm_site');
        return{
            title: tit,
            icon: '<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/mark3.png'
        };
    });

    //marker event
    map.data.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
       map.setZoom(11);
       map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());  // I need to get the position of the marker who i clicked

    });
}
```

how I can make action listener if I initiate marker from geojson?
and how I can get the marker who existing in my map?

please help me, any suggest would be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instances of the [google.maps.Data.Point](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data.Point) class are not exactly a drop-in replacement for traditional google.maps.Marker objects. For starters, they are abstract data, not tied to a particular representation. It's up to the parent [google.maps.Data](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data) layer to decide how to draw them.

However, you can still capture events, with the caveat that the click happens on the Data layer, which receives a `mouseEvent` as argument. This argument contains the feature over which you just clicked.

This means you need to declare:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map.data,'click',function(mouseEvent) {
    var clickedFeature = mouseEvent.feature,
        featureGeometry = clickedFeature.getGeometry(),
        featurePosition = featureGeometry.get();

    map.setCenter(featurePosition); 

});
```

Please take into consideration that ingesting geoJson with the Data layer can result not just in Point geometries. If you get a mix of points, polygons and linestrings, anything different from a point won't return a latLng object when you call its `get` method.

Comment: thank you for your help, I was see that return value of `get` method. but I didn't have any idea for use that. little confuse for Data.feature class. So can I getProperty from that too?

Comment: Sure. Just as you can use getGeometry, you could use getProperty.